# Cypress tests element covering error by iframe running in buddy.works

Tags: node.js, cypress

I am facing  an error when running a few cypress tests in local host in buddy.works . The error occurs when I try to login using the login button.

```
    CypressError: Timed out retrying after 4050ms: `cy.click()` failed because this element:

    `<button id="login_confirm" type="submit" class="w-100 a_loginButton btn btn-primary">Log In</button>`

    is being covered by another element:

    `<iframe style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; z-index: 2147483647;"></iframe>`

    Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.
```

I tried running the tests again by modifying login button clicking code **cy.click({force: true})**, but the button click is not redirecting to the user homepage.

These cypress tests are passing when ran headless in local host.